# How to find database connection leak (for PostgreSQL) application

Tags: database, postgresql

*My environment: Windows XP embedded, Atom N280 CPU, 4G memory, **Postgresql odbc driver***

I noticed there're exception logged once our new developed local applications running for a while (which connected to a PostgreSql 9.2 database):

> remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

I know this indicates a `db connection leak` which caused by **open** a db connection but didn't **close** it properly.

Meanwhile, I can see the keep rising and finally reached over hundred process of `postgres.exe` in system, and the `max_connections` in postgreSQL configuration is **150**.

===================================

I was trying to link these `postgres.exe` to my applications but could't get a clue since the process was created in ODBC driver.    I also enabled the windows performance counter of 'ODBC Connection Pooling', but it only have the overall statistics.

so anyone have suggestion to how to link the db open connection to my application without check each of the individual application code?

Comment: `(0)` check the logfile (maybe first lower max_connections;-) `(1)` kill some connections, and see where it hurts. (if it hurts; leaked connections might not be seen by the application anymore)

Comment: @joop (0)checking the application log might not help since all applications logged with sth like `connection is running out`, and some of them may just the victims.  (1) you mean I randomly kill `postgres.exe` and then check each applications' log to see any abnormal?  But the killed one might be the normal by using one or it just sit in the connection pool.

Comment: 1) Not the application log, the postgres log for the server. 2) No, I meant `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` at the server side http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-admin.html . BTW: when configured, you can see the serverlog from the pgadmin frontend.

Comment: @joop thanks for the replying, 0)I've checked the db side logs(but the logs is not in my hand now), it logged sth like `all connection used out except some left for admin role to connect in`, seems no help for me.  1)not quite sure your purpose, I terminate a connection, then check application log, if it logged some error at the same, then this connection belongs to this application?

Comment: I **hope** it belongs to your application ;-] You can alter the logging, such that the {ip-address+portnum+connectionid+username+databasename} are added to the loglines. That will enable you to detect your application's connections. Please talk to the DBA.